# .htaccess RewriteRule allowing Duplicate content

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess code to do a url Rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^co/prepagos_([a-z]+).htm$ /dir/city.php?scity=$1&pagina=mujeres&pais=2
```

And it works with

1. http://www.angelesinfieles.com/co/prepagos_cali.htm
2. http://www.angelesinfieles.com/co/prepagos_cali.htm?any-text-I-add-here

And I only want #1 to work not #2 because google web master sees this as duplicate content. Any ideas please.

Comment: [You could do that directly from Webmasters Tool with the function available under `Crawl > URL Parameters`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^co/prepagos_([a-z]+)\.htm$ /co/city_view.php?scity=$1&pagina=mujeres&pais=2 [L,QSA]
```

**This will make sure to apply your rewrite rule only when QUERY_STRING is empty.**